# Jquery conditional && not showing expected result

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I'm trying to validate a complicated form. In this example I'm checking all radio buttons have a value

```
if ($('input[name=brand]:checked').val()!="" && $('input[name=section]:checked').val()!="" ) {
    alert("both selected all is well");
    $("a.gobutfton").addClass("ok");
} else{
    alert("They are still not all selected");
}
```

even if just one is clicked I get the "both are selected" alert (there for testing) 
given that I'll have multiple items and form types I can't even get two to behave how I'd imagined they should
http://jsfiddle.net/Lrz8vrdd/1/

Comment: I'd also initially tried putting the radio values into a variable http://jsfiddle.net/Lrz8vrdd/

Comment: If there are no checked radio buttons you are calling .val() on nothing. And the value of .val() on nothing is undefined which will evaluate to true since its not equal to "". You need to add a check that also sees if the buttons are checked first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One or both are "undefined".  Try

```
if ($('input[name=brand]:checked').val() && $('input[name=section]:checked').val())
```

That makes sure that neither one is 0, empty string, undefined or null.

Comment: I thought the "undefined" might have something to do with it and had added an !="undefined" too bu tit was probably not set in the right place or just was never going to work. THis did the trick perfectly thanks.